# How to let Web Browsers on Windows 7 consider the etc/hosts file

Tags: windows, dns, browser, hosts

Under Windows 7, I have edited the `etc/hosts` file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) in order to register several alias for `127.0.0.1`. The changed line:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost proxy.virtual appserver.virtual
```

Whereas I can successfully ping the alias names and access them using *curl* (in a cygwin console), all present web browsers do not resolve the hostnames.

I have already tried to use a Firefox add-on for flushing the DNS cache and another one (ChangeHosts) which is supposed to implant alternative host files, this all does not work.

Unsuccessfully Tested browsers: IE8, recent Chrome, recent Firefox

So, what is wrong there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have not configured your browsers to use proxy. If you are using proxy , exclude your alias names from proxy.